# MS Access add button to form to create new record for specific table

Tags: forms, ms-access, relationship

I have a tabbed form in Access 365 with 2 tabs - the first tab displays fields from Table A and the second tab has fields from Table B. There is a 1 to N relationship defined between Table A and Table B. The primary key (autonumber) from Table A ('ID_TableA') has been copied to Table B and this field is used to define the 1 to N relationship. See below for fields in both tables. Currently if I enter data in the second tab for Table B, the 'ID_TableA' value in Table B will be assigned the value of the 'ID_TableA' in the Table A record the form is currently on.

*How can I use the second tab in my form to create multiple records in Table B that relate to one record in Table A?* I'm thinking adding a navigation button that creates new records in Table B that relate to the same record in Table A. Thoughts/suggestions?

Table A fields: ID_TableA (pk - autonumber), name (text), id (numeric)

Table B fields: ID_TableB (pk - autonumber), ID_TableA (numeric), info (text), id2 (numeric)

Comment: I think a sub-form could achieve this, but I'd like to know if I could do this with a tabbed form.

Comment: Not clear to me what this form set up is. Do you mean a Tab control on a form? Tab page A has data from main form and tab page B has a linked subform? Regardless, can certainly use code to create records in table B using key from table A. Advise not to use exact same field name in multiple tables.

Comment: I struggled on how to explain this one. It is what I understand to be a "tabbed" form - a single form with two separate tabs. The first tab has Table A fields and the second tab has Table B fields.

Comment: @June7 - also curious on how I can use code to create records in Table B using key from Table A.

Comment: Use code (macro or VBA) to execute SQL INSERT action. There are two ways to create a 'tabbed' form: 1) regular form with a Tab control or 2) a Navigation Form object. In both cases, subforms would be needed to display data from multiple table sources.